# postInvalidateDelayed( ) and onDraw( ) behavior when Activity is stopped / restarted

Tags: android

In my App I am trying to change the state / display of a view after 5 seconds by calling `postInvalidateDelayed(5000)`.

I have a question on `postInvalidateDelayed( )` and `onDraw( )` behavior in the following two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

1. postInvalidateDelayed(5000) called for a view "View V" in current Activity "Activity A"
2. user navigates away from the current "Activity A" before the invalidate event can be delivered to "View V" (i.e. "Activity A" is still on the activity stack)
3. user navigates back to "Activity A" using the back button / method `super.onBackPressed( )` (i.e. "Activity A" is not being recreated)

**Scenario 2:**

1. `postInvalidateDelayed(5000)` called for a view "View V" in current Activity "Activity A"
2. user navigates away from the current "Activity A" before the invalidate event can be delivered to "View V" by pressing the "Home" button (i.e. "Activity A" is still on the activity stack)
3. user navigates back to "Activity A" by starting the application again (i.e. "Activity A" is not being recreated)

In the above two scenarios would an invalidate event be delivered to "View V" or would the invalidate event be lost? I'm observing that the invalidate event is lost in these scenarios. What would be the best way to ensure that such an invalidate event can be delivered when the Activity (Activity A) is restarted / resumed?

Would appreciate any inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for this? You could just call `postInvalidateDelayed(5000)` in your `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris, I think I can try that out to see if the App logic works with that.  

For the purpose of understanding Invalidate events better, could you please provide some insights into:  
1. Whether or not Invalidate events scheduled before the Activity is paused or stopped get queued to be delivered when the Activity is resumed or restarted?  

2. In case the above does not happen and Invalidate events are lost, then I think the recommended approach would be to go with what you suggested - calling an Invalidate in onResume( )?  

Thanks in advance for your inputs.